# Need help appending a word as separate letters in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I'm new to programming and I would like to append the randomly chosen word in a list of separate letters(letterList)

```
import random
wordList = ["bird", "dog", "cat", "school", "computer"]
underscoreList = []
letterList = []

word = random.choice(wordList)

for letter in word:
  letterList.append[letter]
  underscoreList.append["_"]
```

Comment: Did you try `l.extend('abc')`?

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: Without any code (I see you added it now), I was answering the question posed in the title "Need help appending a word as separate letters in a list"

Comment: @E.Garvey: `str` are iterables, just like `list`, they're just iterables of length 1 `str` (the individual "characters"). `list.extend` is just a way to all `append` for every item in an input iterable (but faster than a Python level loop), so `l.extend('abc')` is just inserting each character as an element in the `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine, you're just misusing square brackets (used for indexing/lookup) when you want parentheses (used for function/method calls). `append` is a method on `list`, so you need to delimit the argument with parentheses, changing:

```
letterList.append[letter]
underscoreList.append["_"]
```

to:

```
letterList.append(letter)
underscoreList.append("_")
```

Mind you, in this particular case, you could simplify a lot, replacing your loop (and the initial definition of your `list`s) with a simple conversion to `list` and `list` multiplication respectively, leaving just:

```
import random
wordList = ["bird", "dog", "cat", "school", "computer"]

word = random.choice(wordList)

letterList = list(word)  # Converts to list of characters directly
underscoreList = ['_'] * len(word)  # Makes list of underscores of matching length
```

Answer (score -1):

it's append(letter) not append[letter]

Answer (score -1):

```
import random 
wordList = ["bird", "dog", "cat", "school", "computer"] 
underscoreList = [] 
letterList = []
for x in range(3):
    word = random.choice(wordList)
    letterList += [[x for x in word]]
    for letter in word:
        underscoreList.append("_")
print(letterList)
```